# Enter data for missing category in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like

[image]

For each keyword, there are 2 devices - mobile and desktop. If entry for only one device is found, then it should automatically create the entry for other device keeping the data in rest of the columns same. I am currently doing a full outer join which is working fine for the case where one device category is missing but generating duplicates where both devices are present. For example,
my current query is giving the result as

```sql
select a.keyword, b.device, a.rating 
from kw a full outer join kw b 
on a.keyword=b.keyword and a.rating=b.rating
```

[image]

How do I get the result as

[image]

Comment: Posting data as plain text, not pictures of data, and the code that you have so far would help. Also, I believe the tag you want is `snowflake-cloud-data-platform`, assuming that's the database product that you're using. Otherwise, a tag with the platform you are using should be added.

Answer (score 0):

The first step will be to identify records that don't have a paired record. There's a couple of ways to do this, but the easiest is probably just a quick GROUP BY/HAVING:

```
  SELECT keyword
  FROM kw
  GROUP BY keyword
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

You can those join those results back into the original table to generate the new records that are needed:

```
SELECT sk.keyword, 
    CASE WHEN kw.device = 'mobile' THEN 'desktop' ELSE 'mobile' END as device,
    kw.rating
FROM 
    (
      SELECT keyword
      FROM kw
      GROUP BY keyword
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    )sk
    INNER JOIN kw ON kw.keyword = sk.keyword
```

Then you can UNION back in the original table to bring your new records and existing records into a single result set:

```
SELECT sk.keyword, 
    CASE WHEN kw.device = 'mobile' THEN 'desktop' ELSE 'mobile' END as device,
    kw.rating
FROM 
    (
      SELECT keyword
      FROM kw
      GROUP BY keyword
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    )sk
    INNER JOIN kw ON kw.keyword = sk.keyword
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM kw;
```

---

As another option that will scale if you add in more 'devices' is to cross join all the potential `device`/`keyword` combinations and then left join to your original table:

```
SELECT
    fe.keyword,
    fe.device,
    CASE WHEN kw.rating IS NULL THEN max(rating) OVER (PARTITION BY fe.keyword) ELSE kw.rating END AS rating
FROM 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT kw.keyword, kw2.device
      FROM kw, kw kw2
    ) fe
    LEFT OUTER JOIN kw ON kw.keyword = fe.keyword
        AND kw.device = fe.device;
```